# Does the laser sight have any advantages?

Tags: metro-last-light

Because of the fact that the laser sight seems to remove the reticle without actually providing a dot, only a beam, my experience with it was limited to shooting rats in Venice. Does the laser sight have any effect other than replacing the reticle with an (arguably inferior) laser beam, like reduced hip-fire spread? Will the laser give my position away to enemies? Can I disable it somehow without removing it?

Answer (score 2):

**Laser sight** is intended to be used **with Red Dot Sight** to make effective crosshair.When you zoom in with both attachments you will see your red dot in the center of your sights.

I'm not sure if red dot will appear outside sights,I don't remember seeing it myself but few [pictures](http://images.wikia.com/metro2033/images/8/88/LaserSightBastard.png) say differently.

Laser **won't give you away** enemies completely ignore it.

Comment: The part about the laser sight being meant to be used with red dot is highly dubious. I've had a few visual bugs, maybe the abscence of the dot is one of them. Any idea if it affects gun performance directly?

Comment: On metro wiki there is a mention that it increases accuracy,but I can't confirm if it refers to 2033 or LL or even both.See for yourself
http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Attachments

Comment: @Arremer Perhaps by increase accuracy they mean that you will shoot  more straight because you have something to aim with from the hip.

Answer (score 2):

When crouched and not moving, laser sights will give you 100% accurate hip fire shots.

This can be especially effective at close range, with a suppressor.

Comment: Good try, but unfortunately this isn't really what the question is asking for.

Comment: Actually, @Texenox, this is exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: @Timelord64 I keep getting confused from how these answers are worded, wow.